# how many 9 digit numbers have the property that the product of their firsts and last digits is even?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 9 digit numbers have the property that the product of their firsts and last digits is even?

I tried listing them out, but there's probably way too many. This is a basic counting problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that a product is even iff at least one factor is even

Comment: Hint: How many 9 digit numbers have their first digit even? How many 9 digit numbers have their last digit even? How many 9 digit numbers have their first and last digits even?

Comment: Note that you have to specify whether the leftmost digit can be 0.  Also, as I read the problem, the 7 *inner* digits are not constrained in any way.

Answer (score 1):

The product of the first and last digits is even iff they are not both odd. There are $9×10$ ways to choose the first and last digits; of those $5×5$ result in an odd product due to both digits being odd. The remaining seven digits may be chosen arbitrarily, so the answer is $(9×10-5×5)10^7=65\cdot10^7$.